# Using PostSharp with F# - Need documentation with working example

Tags: f#, postsharp

I have a need to capture the input and output of F# functions and decided to try using PostSharp. I was unable to find documentation and a working F# example for using PostSharp with F#. Does anyone know where I might find such?

Comment: I can confirm that it works with an OnMethodBoundaryAspect on a public member of an F# class. However, I implemented the aspect attribute using 'regular' C#. So, all in all it should work just the same as with C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostSharp does not officially support F#. It may partially work, because PostSharp works at MSIL level, but there's no guarantee that everything will work, and since it is not supported, bugs will not be solved.