# Is there any documentation on how to use Glimpse with F# and Suave?

Tags: f#, glimpse

I am trying to see if there are any instructions/documentation on how to use Glimpse in an F# project? I looked through the list of adapters they have on their website and I didn't see anything specific to F#. They have ones for ASP.NET MVC and EF but if you using something like Suave (https://suave.io/), how do you go about integrating it into your project?

Comment: I don't see the need for the close votes. It is not a subjective recommendation question, e.g. pick the best for me type of question. He is looking for documentation. I have asked these before: [Using NLog with F# Interactive in Visual Studio - Need documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14657954/1243762) and [Using PostSharp with F# - Need documentation with working example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14653231/1243762)